What are the risks and impacts of switching CentOS 7 repository configuration to vault.centos.org?
I am facing an issue with yum failing to resolve mirrorlist.centos.org for CentOS 7. To resolve this, I am considering updating my repository configuration to replace mirrorlist.centos.org with vault.centos.org.
I have the following questions:
Will this change affect the stability or functionality of my current applications, such as PostgreSQL, HTTP, Tomcat, and WordPress?
Is it safe to use vault.centos.org temporarily, or could this lead to potential issues like corruption or software conflicts?
I plan to upgrade my OS soon but need a temporary fix for now.
[root@localhost ~]# sudo yum install postgis30_11 postgis30_11-utils

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org?arch=x86_64&release=7&repo=sclo-rh error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: centos-sclo-rh/x86_64
"
